# Check if $_FILES is html

Tags: php, html, file

How do I check what file `$_FILES` is? I've seen ways, where MIME-TYPE is used, but I've read that checking the MIME-TYPE is not a save method. I know how it works with images. There you can use Attributes like "IMAGE_JPG" or "IMAGE_PNG". But "TEXT_HTML" doesnt exist.

So please help me, i would like to use the only proper Way.

Answer (score 2):

`mime_content_type` can helps you.

> Returns the MIME content type for a file as determined by using information from the `magic.mime` file.

```
if(mime_content_type($_FILES['name']) == 'text/html'){
    // HTML file
}
```

If you want to check another mime-types, you can see [my gist](https://gist.github.com/Kristories/3072445).

Comment: Yes, but the MIME-TYPE is easy to change by the user. This is not a save method.

Comment: Did you try it? :) 
Try to change your image extension to another

Comment: @MyNameisKev One thing is the mime key on the $_FILES variable, that is set by the browser. But suggested solution runs checks on the uploaded file itself independently.

Comment: So.. what should i use? Pathinfo or mime_content_type? What is more secure?

Comment: **`pathinfo` is just information about the file**. You have `test.php`, `pathinfo` will show `.php` extension. If you change `.php` to `.html`, `pathinfo` will show `.html` extension. Just information about the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pathinfo()`

```
$file_parts = pathinfo($filename);
switch($file_parts['extension'])
{
    case "html":
    each 'Your file is HTML file';
    break;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. I try it. All i want is a secure System.